# How to detect if a click is inside an element yet not on an image?

Tags: jquery

I am looking at a `main` element holding images. These images can be sorted (e.g. on subject) meaning that sometimes a few images are visible, and a few images are hidden.

I wish to detect a click inside the `main` section, yet not on an image, to show all images again.

I'm confused as of why the following is not working, and I was hoping someone could point out what I am doing wrong.

```
$("main").onclick().not('img') {
  $('img').show();
};
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your HTML will provide valuable context.  Always check the error console as your jquery syntax is also wrong. Try  `$("main :not(img)").on("click", function(){ $(img).show() })`

Comment: That code will throw error in your browser dev tool console. Start by checking that error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first use correct syntax and method, then within the event handler function check the `target`

```
$("main").click(function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).is('img')) {
    // click didn't happen on image
    // do what you need here
  }
});
```

Comment: @hmd Well w3fools isn't a quality reference source either https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main

Comment: that did the trick, however, I am still confused as of why `main :not(img)` wouldn't work. I'm having trouble finding a good article or reference on W3 for .not()

Comment: `$("main").not('img')` says .... a `<main>` element that is not an `<img>` . `$('main :not(img)')` might work but only if an actual descendant element is clicked. Any whitespace in the body of the main that isn't in another element would not register